# Changing a 0 or 1 value to "Yes" and "No" in APEX report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a report region on my page and it's getting data from a `students` table. Within that table, there's a column called `cv_lodged` which is either 1 or 0 representing Yes or No. In the report it shows this columns data as 0 or 1, I want to change it to show Yes or No.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put a `CASE` statement in your query

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN cv_lodged = 1 
             THEN 'Yes'
             ELSE 'No'
         END) cv_lodged,
       other_columns
  FROM students
```

If this is something that is likely to be common, you're probably better served creating a function that converts your pseudo-boolean data to a string.  Something like

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_bool_to_str( p_num IN NUMBER )
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
  IF( p_num = 1 )
  THEN 
    RETURN 'Yes';
  ELSE
    RETURN 'No';
  END IF;
END;
```

that you would call in your query

```
SELECT my_bool_to_str( cv_lodged ) cv_lodged,
       other_columns
  FROM students
```

Answer (score 0):

I've usually just created a static LOV in Shared Components called YES1_NO0, with 2 entries: 'Yes' -> 1, 'No' -> 0.
In Interactive Reports you can then change these columns. To do this, edit the column of the IR. Change 'Display Type' to 'Display as Text (based on LOV, escape special characters)'. Then under 'List of Values' set 'Column Filter Type' to 'Use Named List of Values to Filter Exact Match' and select the named LOV.
But sure, you can totally do this in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is a simpler way to do this.

First open the APEX page with the "Yes/No" item as developer and click on the item to open the page item settings.

Change the *Settings* value from `Use component settings` to `Custom`.

Afterwards change the `Yes Value` to `1` and the `No Value` to `0`.

[image]

This solution has some advantages:

1. No need to *decode* the value 1 or 0 to Y or N (`select decode(mycolumn, 1, 'Y', 'N') from mytable where id = 123;`) or `select case when ...`
2. No need to *decode* the submitted value back to 1 or 0 from Y or N